# Cannot change the laravel app name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using `php artisan app:name L&K Biomedics` to set the name of the app. But I get an error saying,

```
'L' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm new to Laravel. What I'm doing wrong here.

[image]

And is there a way to undo this command? I mean, if it changed the name to **L&** how can I change back it?

Comment: Side note: You'll type your `app:name` a **lot**. Keep it something short - ~20 characters is a lot and will drive you bonkers. Frankly, I think it's silly to change it from `App` unless you're frequently working on multiple Laravel apps at the same time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should remove spaces and `&` from the app name. Name app is basically a [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php).

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 18):

**You can have spaces in app name.** You can achieve this by using single quotes in your **.env** file, set:

```
APP_NAME='Company Name'
```

Restart your application by running command:

```
php artisan serve
```

Refresh your application in the browser.

It works fine, however i don't know if the space in the app name will be affecting any specific functionality of the app.

Answer (score 5):

You need  to study the naming standard  a name can't  include &

Answer (score 3):

**Spaces** and **&** not allow so you can try this:

```
php artisan app:name KLBiomedicsEnterprices
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the name in the `.env` file, and don't use spaces or any special character.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration). As other people mentioned before, spaces and special characters are not allowed.

Use the artisan command: `php artisan app:name KLBiomedicsEnterprices`
What this will do, is change the application Namespace from App to KLBiomedicsEnterprices.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Config->app.php and put this code

`'title' => 'Library System',`

Answer (score 0):

in your terminal:php artisan app:name Yourapplicationname

then in your editor(eg:brackets or notepad)

Open config,then in app.php,alter the following
'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Yourapplicationname'),

then

restart your application:
"php artisan serve" in your terminal
then refresh your application in the browser(locahost:8000 etc)
**This worked for me**

**NB:You cant have spaces in your app name**

Answer (score 0):

Aside from putting with single quote in your .env file

```
APP_NAME='Your Project Name'
```

Don't forget to run this command because it will not work if you won't clear the configuration cache

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Then restart your application

```
php artisan serve
```