cannot change the default name in app.php
In essence, I'm trying to change the name of my website from Laravel to my own, however even after making changes inside the app.php file and refreshing the page, the default name, "Laravel" remains the same.
this is inside my welcome.blade.php code:
<title>Welcome to {{ config('app.name') }}</title>

This is inside config/app.php:
'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Smart Medical Health'),

How do I fix this ?
I already change the code from this
'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'),

to
'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Smart Medical Health'),.
I do anticipate a change in the name.

Welcome to SO.  Please try searching before posting a new question, there are many questions and answers about this here already.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67961570/change-laravel-project-name, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087858/how-to-change-application-name-in-laravel-5-8, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046823/how-to-get-the-application-name-in-laravel, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48807788/revert-laravel-app-name, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379957/cannot-change-the-laravel-app-name, ...

The docs describe how env() works - it will look for the first value (APP_NAME) in the .env file and use that if it exists; if not, the 2nd value will be used.  In your case you've changed the 2nd value, but that will only be used if you have no APP_NAME already configured in your .env.

i already try but still not working

Did you clear the config cache after changing the .env file? php artisan config:clear
